# How would you know if "DataTable.Load()" finished loading?

Tags: .net, datatable, datareader

How would you know if all result data are loaded in the `DataTable` when you use `DataTable.Load`? Or rather, how would we know if the `DataReader` has finished loading the data?

Code:

```
'Connection, command etc.
Dim Reader as SqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
Dim SomeDataTable as new DataTable()
SomeDataTable.load(Reader); 'When will loading be finished or how would you know?
```

I'm using VB.NET

**Update:**

Here's my original code:

```
Private Function LoadPRS(ByVal Username As String) As DataTable
    Dim PRSList As New DataTable

    Using Connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBCS").ToString)
        Using Command As New SqlCommand _
            ("select * from products", Connection)

            Connection.Open()
            Using Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
                PRSList.Load(Reader)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return PRSList
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, that method is synchronous. You know it has finished because the method returns to you. If it didn't "finish", it would have thrown an exception.

Comment: Really? So I could do `DataTable.Load(Reader)` inside `Using Reader as SqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader() ... End Using` without exception? 'Coz I'll be returning the `DataTable` I'm afraid it wouldn't be finished until I do return...

Comment: @domanokz yes; that is exactly what I mean. Most asynchronous methods will be obvious, i.e. `BeginLoad`, `StartLoad` etc, and would return (typically) `IAsyncResult`, or `Task[<T>]`, or take some kind of completion callback.